# NTP client displaying reference, originate, receive and transmit timestamps periodically with graceful shutdown in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, networking, udp

based on this stackoverflow topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150289/15270760 I have decided to create a simple NTP client displaying difference between NTP server response and DateTime.Now called right after receiving NTP response. I was just curious of the result. I have read both RFC's 2030 and 1305 and it appered to me that there are four different timestamps, not as I expected, one. I have decided to cover all four of them. I was just curious of the result, again. I humbly ask for a code review based on this snippet of code. At the beggining I would like to emphasise that this is a simple console application so please don't be too harsh on me for keeping the `Main()` method name.

```
public sealed class NTP
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150289/15270760
        const string ntpServer = "time.windows.com";
        var address = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList.FirstOrDefault();

        if (address is null) throw new Exception("No ntp server found");

        var udpClient = new UdpClient();
        var ntpServerEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, 123);

        udpClient.Connect(ntpServerEndpoint);

        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;

        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        
        Task.WaitAny(new Task[]
        {
            Task.Run(() => DisplayNtpServerResponsePeriodically(udpClient, ntpServerEndpoint, tokenSource)),
            Task.Run(() => ReadUserInput(tokenSource)),
        });
        
        udpClient.Close();
    }

    private static void ReadUserInput(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        while (userInput != "q" && userInput != "Q")
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
            
        Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private static async Task DisplayNtpServerResponsePeriodically(UdpClient udpClient,
        IPEndPoint ntpServerEndpoint, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var bytesBuffer = new byte[48];
        
            // Based on RFC 2030:
            // Leap Indicator: First two bits - warning of an impending leap second to be inserted/deleted
            // Version Number: Middle three bits - indicating version number, 011 equal to IPv4 only
            // Mode values: Last three bits - indicating the mode, 011 equal to client mode
            bytesBuffer[0] = 0b00011011;
            
            udpClient.Send(bytesBuffer);
            bytesBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref ntpServerEndpoint);

            var serverResponseReceivedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            
            var ntpServerTimestamps = GetNtpTimeStamps(bytesBuffer);

            Console.WriteLine($"{ntpServerTimestamps.ToString(serverResponseReceivedDateTime)}");
            
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }

    private static NtpServerTimestamps GetNtpTimeStamps(byte[] bytesBuffer)
    {
        var fieldsIndexes = new int[] { 16, 24, 32, 40 };

        var timestampsArray = new DateTime[4];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < fieldsIndexes.Length; i++)
        {
            ulong seconds = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytesBuffer, fieldsIndexes[i]);
            ulong secondsFraction = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytesBuffer, fieldsIndexes[i] + 4);
            
            seconds = ConvertToLittleEndianUnsignedLong(seconds);
            secondsFraction = ConvertToLittleEndianUnsignedLong(secondsFraction);
            
            var milliseconds = (seconds * 1000) + ((secondsFraction * 1000) / 0x100000000L);
            
            var dateTime =
                (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);

            timestampsArray[i] = dateTime;
        }

        return new NtpServerTimestamps(timestampsArray);
    }

    // Source: stackoverflow.com/a/3294698/162671
    static uint ConvertToLittleEndianUnsignedLong(ulong x)
    {
        return (uint) (((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) +
                       ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8) +
                       ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) +
                       ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24));
    }

    private sealed class NtpServerTimestamps
    {
        private DateTime _referenceTimestamp { get; }
        private DateTime _originateTimestamp { get; }
        private DateTime _receiveTimestamp { get; }
        private DateTime _transmitTimestamp { get; }

        public NtpServerTimestamps(DateTime[] datetimeArray)
        {
            _referenceTimestamp = datetimeArray[0].ToLocalTime();
            _originateTimestamp = datetimeArray[1].ToLocalTime();
            _receiveTimestamp = datetimeArray[2].ToLocalTime();
            _transmitTimestamp = datetimeArray[3].ToLocalTime();
        }

        public string ToString(DateTime serverResponseReceivedDateTime)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"-------------------NTP Server Response-------------------");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Reference: {_referenceTimestamp}:{_referenceTimestamp.Millisecond}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Originate: {_originateTimestamp}:{_originateTimestamp.Millisecond}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Receive: {_receiveTimestamp}:{_receiveTimestamp.Millisecond}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Transmit: {_transmitTimestamp}:{_transmitTimestamp.Millisecond}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Now: {serverResponseReceivedDateTime}:{serverResponseReceivedDateTime.Millisecond}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("");
            
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Reference-Now difference: {(serverResponseReceivedDateTime - _referenceTimestamp).TotalMilliseconds}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Originate-Now difference: {(serverResponseReceivedDateTime - _originateTimestamp).TotalMilliseconds}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Receive-Now difference: {(serverResponseReceivedDateTime - _receiveTimestamp).TotalMilliseconds}");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Transmit-Now difference: {(serverResponseReceivedDateTime - _transmitTimestamp).TotalMilliseconds}");

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my observations

#### `DisplayNtpServerResponsePeriodically`

- `0b00011011`: I would suggest to move such magic number into a `const`/`static readonly`
- I would also recommend to do not reuse outgoing buffer as an incoming buffer
- Last but not least `Task.Delay` should also receive the `CancellationToken` to avoid waiting "unnecessary" 5 seconds

```
// Based on RFC 2030:
// Leap Indicator: First two bits - warning of an impending leap second to be inserted/deleted
// Version Number: Middle three bits - indicating version number, 011 equal to IPv4 only
// Mode values: Last three bits - indicating the mode, 011 equal to client mode
private static readonly byte[] Request_Bytes = new byte[] { 0b00011011 };
private static async Task DisplayNtpServerResponsePeriodically(UdpClient udpClient,
    IPEndPoint ntpServerEndpoint, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        udpClient.Send(Request_Bytes);
        var bytesBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref ntpServerEndpoint);

        var serverResponseReceivedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var ntpServerTimestamps = GetNtpTimeStamps(bytesBuffer);

        Console.WriteLine($"{ntpServerTimestamps.ToString(serverResponseReceivedDateTime)}");

        await Task.Delay(5000, tokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

- BTW: `ntpServerTimestamps.ToString(serverResponseReceivedDateTime)`: here the `ToString` name feels really unnatural

  - Most of the time `ToString` can receive a formatter parameter
  - So, I would suggest to find some different name here

#### `GetNtpTimeStamps`

- Yet again move the magic numbers into `const`/`static readonly` fields

  - Please find some better naming here, I've just extracted them from the method

```
private static readonly DateTime baseTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
private static readonly int[] fieldsIndexes = new int[] { 16, 24, 32, 40 };
private const int MilliSecondMultiplier = 1_000;
private const long MilliSecondDivider = 0x100_000_000;
```

- I would also suggest to use a `List` for timestamps rather than an array

  - It is much easier to use (`.Add` instead of `[i]`)
  - It allows you to use `foreach` instead of `for`
- You don't need to use brackets because of the [operator precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)

```
private static NtpServerTimestamps GetNtpTimeStamps(byte[] bytesBuffer)
{
    var timestamps = new List<DateTime>(fieldsIndexes.Length);
    foreach (var index in fieldsIndexes)
    {
        ulong seconds = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytesBuffer, index);
        ulong secondsFraction = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytesBuffer, index + 4);

        seconds = ConvertToLittleEndianUnsignedLong(seconds);
        secondsFraction = ConvertToLittleEndianUnsignedLong(secondsFraction);

        var milliseconds = seconds * MilliSecondMultiplier + secondsFraction * MilliSecondMultiplier / MilliSecondDivider;
        timestamps.Add(baseTime.AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds));
    }

    return new NtpServerTimestamps(timestamps.ToArray());
}
```

#### `NtpServerTimestamps`'s ctor

- It feels a bit clumsy to receive an array  and then use it to retrieve items based on their positions

  - Maybe passing all four parameters separately is more explicit and less fragile

#### `NtpServerTimestamps`'s `ToString`

- If you introduce the following two helper methods

```
private string FormatDateTimeToDisplay(string prefix, DateTime timestamp)
    => $"{prefix}: {timestamp}:{timestamp.Millisecond}";

private string FormatDateTimesToDisplay(string prefix, DateTime received, DateTime timestamp)
    => $"{prefix}-Now difference: {(received - timestamp).TotalMilliseconds}";
```

- And you are replacing the `StringBuilder` to a simple `string.Join(Environment.NewLine,` then your code would become much more readable

```
public string ToString(DateTime serverResponseReceivedDateTime)
    => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new[] {
        "-------------------NTP Server Response-------------------",
        FormatDateTimeToDisplay("Reference", _referenceTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimeToDisplay("Originate", _originateTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimeToDisplay("Receive", _receiveTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimeToDisplay("Transmit", _transmitTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimeToDisplay("Now", serverResponseReceivedDateTime),
        "",
        FormatDateTimesToDisplay("Reference", serverResponseReceivedDateTime, _referenceTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimesToDisplay("Originate", serverResponseReceivedDateTime, _originateTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimesToDisplay("Receive", serverResponseReceivedDateTime, _receiveTimestamp),
        FormatDateTimesToDisplay("Transmit", serverResponseReceivedDateTime, _transmitTimestamp)
    });
```

- Yet again the `ToString` name feels a bit weird here